# Temp Table VS Table variable

Tags: sql-server

I have to write a table function so I prototyped the query in SQL Server and used a temp table but when I change it to a table variable the query goes from taking approx. 1 minute to more than 2 hours.

The second code is this one:

```
DECLARE @DETALLE TABLE
(
    FECHA smalldatetime,
    NO_OP NVARCHAR(100),
    MONTO FLOAT,
    PLAZO INT,
    CLIENTE NVARCHAR(100)
)

-- CALCULO EL PLAZO POR EL MONTO, EL CUAL SERA EL NUMERADOR --
--DROP TABLE #DETALLE
INSERT INTO @DETALLE
    SELECT 
        D.FECHA, D.NO_OP,
        MONTO = (D.CAPITAL+D.INTERESES)/1000000,
        PLAZO = CAST(D.FECHA_VCTO-D.FECHA AS INT),
        CLIENTE = CASE 
                     WHEN MIN_MAY = 'N' THEN 'MINORISTA'
                     WHEN M.ORIGEN = 'MESA LIQUIDEZ' THEN 'CLIENTE LIQUIDEZ'
                     WHEN M.ORIGEN IS NULL AND MIN_MAY = 'S' AND COD_SUCURSAL = '246' THEN 'EMPRESAS SALES'
                     ELSE 'OTRO MAYORISTA' 
                  END
    --INTO #DETALLE
    FROM 
        BCI_RIF_ODS.dbo.Tab_Detalle_DAP AS D 
    INNER JOIN 
        BCI_RI_ODS.dbo.Cliente_Traduce AS C ON (C.CLIENTE_ID = D.CLIENTE_ID)
    LEFT JOIN 
        BCI_RIF_ODS.dbo.TabMae_CliMesa AS M ON (D.CLIENTE_ID = M.CLIENTE_ID)
    WHERE 
        FECHA >= '20180101' AND FECHA_VCTO > FECHA

SELECT 
    D1.CLIENTE, D1.FECHA,
    NUMERADOR = SUM(D1.PLAZO*D1.MONTO),
    MONTO = D2.MONTO,
    FACTOR = SUM(D1.PLAZO*D1.MONTO)/D2.Monto
FROM
    @DETALLE D1 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         CLIENTE, FECHA,
         MONTO = SUM(MONTO)
     FROM 
         @DETALLE
     GROUP BY 
         CLIENTE, FECHA) D2 ON (D1.CLIENTE = D2.CLIENTE AND D1.Fecha = D2.Fecha)
GROUP BY 
    D1.CLIENTE, D1.Fecha, D2.MONTO
```

Comment: How many rows are being inserted into the table variable?  In general, table variables are not optimal for more than a few dozen rows.

Comment: IMHO, it depends in the ammount of data that you want to store....if it is an small ammount of data you can use a table variable without issues, but if you are working with a decent ammount of data you should use temp table, because, with the temp table you can take more advantage of the sql server, like, statitstics and the optimizer.

Comment: @Hackerman it's pretty much a big set but I'm trying to build a table-valued function so the choice of using temp tables is not real, what other choice do I have?

Comment: @SeanLange a source would be useful because I haven't found anything about this specifically regarding table-valued functions

Comment: If you are trying to implement a table valued function why do you want to use a temp table or table variable in the first place? That indicates you have more than a single select statement in your function which means it is a multi-statement table valued function and the performance of those is usually worse than even a scalar function. Perhaps what we need to do here is help you build an efficient inline table valued function that doesn't need temp tables or variables at all.

Comment: @SeanLange I could include the table I'm selecting the data from inside the second SELECT but wouldn't that be unclear ? I thought it was better for code to be legible than functional (specially if the code itself takes 1 min aprox when using temp tables instead of variable tables)

Comment: A table function with variables and such will not perform well at all. To be honest, 1 minute seems awfully long for any query to me unless we are talking return a million rows or more. And that in a function sounds like it might not be the best approach. From the code posted here using a table is just adding overhead because it has to make a copy of all the data and then select from it instead of just selecting the data you need.

Comment: @SeanLange so what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to make another copy of your data to then just perform an aggregate. You could use a cte here instead. Something like this will likely perform a lot better than copying data from one table to a variable.

```
with DETALLE as
(
    -- CALCULO EL PLAZO POR EL MONTO, EL CUAL SERA EL NUMERADOR --
    SELECT 
        D.FECHA, D.NO_OP,
        MONTO = (D.CAPITAL+D.INTERESES)/1000000,
        PLAZO = CAST(D.FECHA_VCTO-D.FECHA AS INT),
        CLIENTE = CASE 
                        WHEN MIN_MAY = 'N' THEN 'MINORISTA'
                        WHEN M.ORIGEN = 'MESA LIQUIDEZ' THEN 'CLIENTE LIQUIDEZ'
                        WHEN M.ORIGEN IS NULL AND MIN_MAY = 'S' AND COD_SUCURSAL = '246' THEN 'EMPRESAS SALES'
                        ELSE 'OTRO MAYORISTA' 
                    END
    FROM 
        BCI_RIF_ODS.dbo.Tab_Detalle_DAP AS D 
    INNER JOIN 
        BCI_RI_ODS.dbo.Cliente_Traduce AS C ON (C.CLIENTE_ID = D.CLIENTE_ID)
    LEFT JOIN 
        BCI_RIF_ODS.dbo.TabMae_CliMesa AS M ON (D.CLIENTE_ID = M.CLIENTE_ID)
    WHERE 
        FECHA >= '20180101' AND FECHA_VCTO > FECHA
)

SELECT 
    D1.CLIENTE, D1.FECHA,
    NUMERADOR = SUM(D1.PLAZO*D1.MONTO),
    MONTO = D2.MONTO,
    FACTOR = SUM(D1.PLAZO*D1.MONTO)/D2.Monto
FROM
    DETALLE D1 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         CLIENTE, FECHA,
         MONTO = SUM(MONTO)
     FROM 
         DETALLE
     GROUP BY 
         CLIENTE, FECHA) D2 ON (D1.CLIENTE = D2.CLIENTE AND D1.Fecha = D2.Fecha)
GROUP BY 
    D1.CLIENTE, D1.Fecha, D2.MONTO
```

Comment: I get an error: Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.

Comment: Then perhaps you could share your code? Apparently you are trying to use this as the body of a function? I am helping at an extreme disadvantage here and coding in the dark.

Comment: @eduardo0 Please take some time to learn about the two types of table-valued functions (TVP). The simplest form is the inline TVP - which is the most suitable one for the query Sean gave you. Contrast that with the form you were likely using - which is the multi-statement TVP. In that form, you define your table in the function declaration and populate it (i.e., insert into it) within the function logic.